# What causes incessant scrotal sac movements?

Tags: urology, body-temperature, reflex-impulse, testicles

According to Wikipedia, scrotal sac movements are to serve the purpose of regulating the temperature of the testicles. They are at slightly lower temperature than the human body, so the scrotal sac moves away when the temperature of the sac needs to be reduced, and move close to the body when it needs to be increased.

But do incessant scrotal sac movements denote that this thermo-regulation mechanism has collapsed? One of my friends is experiencing incessant movements of the scrotal sac, both in the above manner (close to and away from the body), as well as laterally. The same hasn't stopped for >48 hrs at least, and is not accompanied by discomfort of any kind at all. Is this normal, or does this denote some ailment?

(Since there is no discomfort involved, I though it was better to ask here first before advising him to visit a doctor.)

What causes these incessant movements? And, if there is an abnormality here, even then, what causes these incessant movements?

Comment: I tentatively chose some tags, according to what made sense to me. Please change these if doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "incessant scrotum movements"? Are they literally moving without any external force being applied to them?

Comment: Alcohol use, drug use, medication, excessive masturbation, hormone levels, underwear choice, plain old gravity, obsessive compulsive observation of their genitalia... Take your pick, all are just as likely.

Comment: I vote to close as personal health question; "*One of my friends is experiencing...*". Your friend should go see a doctor if he is worried about this.